# How to block spam email by subject on Zimbra server

Tags: spam-prevention, mail-server, zimbra, spamassassin

How can I block spam email by subject?
I tried following [this blog post](http://vinayrana007.wordpress.com/2013/11/29/block-spam-via-subject-line-in-zimbra-server/), but it doesn't work.

It uses `custom_header_checks` and define some parameters, I did try such parameters and restart the services but it still doesn't works.

Are there any other ways to prevent spam in Zimbra mail server?

I use FOSS 7.2.7.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use parentheses. For example (from the link in the question):

```
/^subject.*From U.S. Ambassador to Nigeria/ DISCARD #spam rule to msgs from Nigeria
```

Answer (score 0):

The content in OP's link looks like it was copied from [here](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/King0770-Notes-Header-Checks#Section_IV_-_Header_checks_syntax_by_example):

The header checks lost their formatting so:

```
`/^Subject.*)From U.S. Ambassador to Nigeria/ DISCARD #spam rule no msgs from Nigeria`
```

Should look like:

```
`/^Subject:(.*)From U.S. Ambassador to Nigeria/   DISCARD #spam rule no msgs from Nigeria`
```